# How to use manage data operation on Java SDK

Tags: java-sdk

I was not able to find any tutorial or an example on manage data operation of Java sdk. I tried to build a sample using the Java API documentation. But it's too complicated. If anyone can show me how to do this I am really thankful. Sample code or if you can point out any tutorial or an example that would be fine also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you need but I have written some code for a Flutter plugin that might help to clear at least some things up: Check out this code snippet:

```java
private SubmitTransactionResponse doManageData(final String seed, String name, String value) throws Exception {
        setServerAndNetwork();
        KeyPair keyPair = KeyPair.fromSecretSeed(seed);
        AccountResponse sourceAccount = server.accounts().account(keyPair.getAccountId());

        ManageDataOperation operation = new ManageDataOperation.Builder(name, value.getBytes())
                .setSourceAccount(keyPair.getAccountId())
                .build();
        Transaction transaction = new Transaction.Builder(sourceAccount, network)
                .addOperation(operation)
                .setTimeout(TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS)
                .setOperationFee(100)
                .build();
        try {
            transaction.sign(keyPair);
            SubmitTransactionResponse response = server.submitTransaction(transaction);
            LOGGER.info("manageData: SubmitTransactionResponse: \uD83D\uDC99 Success? : " + response.isSuccess() + " \uD83D\uDC99 ");
            LOGGER.info(G.toJson(response));
            Log.d(TAG, response.isSuccess() ? "manageData transaction is SUCCESSFUL" : "manageData transaction failed");
            return response;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String msg = "Failed to manageData: ";
            LOGGER.severe(msg + e.getMessage());
            throw new Exception(msg, e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Many thanks for your support. I have figured it out thanks to your code snippet. Now it's working.